# Benchmarking an application in a fully loaded machine

Tags: c++, c, time, benchmarking

I need to "time" or benchmark a number crunching application written in C/C++. The problem is that the machine where I run the program is usually full of people doing similar things, so the CPUs are always at full load.

I thought about using functions from time.h liket "get time of the day" (don't remember the exact syntax, sorry) and similars, but I am afraid they would not be good for this case, am I right?

And the program "time" from bash, gave me some errors long time ago.

Also the problem is, that sometimes I need to get timings in the range of 0.5 secs and so on.

Anybody has a hint?

P.S.: compiler is gcc and in some cases nvcc (NVIDIA)
P.S.2: in my benchmarks I just want to measure the execution time between two parts of the main function

Comment: `clock()` from `time.h` should do what you want...

Comment: Mentioning what you are trying to test with your benchmarks would really help answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your other recent questions, you seem to be using *MPI* for parallelisation. **Assuming this question is within the same context**, then the simplest way to time your application would be to use [MPI_Wtime()](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Wtime.html).

From the man page:

> This subroutine returns the current
>   value of time as a double precision
>   floating point number of seconds. This
>   value represents elapsed time since
>   some point in the past. This time in
>   the past will not change during the
>   life of the task. You are responsible
>   for converting the number of seconds
>   into other units if you prefer.

Example usage:

```
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int rc, taskid;
    double t_start, t_end;

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&taskid); 

    t_start = MPI_Wtime();

    /* .... your computation kernel .... */

    t_end = MPI_Wtime();

    /* make sure all processes have completed */
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (taskid == 0) {
        printf("Elapsed time: %1.2f seconds\n", t_start - t_end);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The advantage of this is that we let the underlying MPI library handle platform specific ways of handling time, although you might want to use [MPI_Wtick()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mpi_wtick) to determine the resolution of the timer used on each platform.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did not know this about MPI. But in this case my question if focused in just gcc and nvcc. I will have a look at this

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention which compiler you are using, but with GNU's g++ I usually set the `-pg` flag to build with profiling informations.

Each time you run the application, it will create an output file that, parsed with `gprof` application, will give you lots of information about the performances.

See [this](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html) for starters.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to meaningfully compare timings from programs running for such a short time.  Usually the solution is to run multiple times.

The time builtin in bash (or /usr/bin/time) will report time actually used by the processor, which will be more useful on a loaded machine than wall-clock time, but there is too much going on to really compare timings on a fine grain – huge differences of orders of magnitude will still be apparent.

You can also use clock to get a [rough estimate](http://codepad.org/Rnp1qyiB):

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

struct Timer {
  std::clock_t _start, _stop;
  Timer() : _start(std::clock()) {}
  void restart() { _start = std::clock(); }
  void stop() { _stop = std::clock(); }
  std::clock_t clocks() const { return _stop - _start; }
  double secs() const { return double(clocks()) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC; }
};

int main() {
  Timer t;
  //run_some_code();
  t.stop();
  std::cout << "That took " << t.secs() << " seconds.\n";
  return 0;
}
```